# How do I delay the start of the following fade out command?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would like the delay the start of the following command and would appreciate any recommendation(s).  I am a beginner at this and Thank you in advance.

Sample Text

Comment: use settimeout,

Comment: Please provide your code. Preferably in either jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Put CSS in separate blocks, right now it's not readable.

Comment: <div class="xr_ap xr_ac c2" id="xr_xpxr_40">
      <span class="xr_annt animated fadeOut c1" id="xr_uid_10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="xr_txt Normal_text c4">
      <span class="xr_annt animated fadeOut c3">Sample Text</span>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Use  animation 
Refer [animation css](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/)

You can delay the animation by setting the `animation-delay`: the time between the element being loaded and the start of the animation sequence.

In our code animation delay is set as 3s `-webkit-animation: fadeout 5s linear 3s forwards;`

```css
.fadeOut {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #191970;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 5s linear 3s forwards;
  animation: fadeout 5s linear 3s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="xr_ap xr_ac c2" id="xr_xpxr_40"> 
<span class="xr_annt animated fadeOut c1" id="xr_uid_10"></span> </div>
<div class="xr_txt Normal_text c4"> 
<span class="xr_annt animated fadeOut c3">Sample Text</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am unable to get your suggestion to work.

Comment: I already have a animation delay comment in the fadeOut command and would simply like to delay the entire command from loading by a few seconds -

Comment: My HTML code for the command is:  
<div class="xr_ap xr_ac c2" id="xr_xpxr_40"> <span class="xr_annt animated fadeOut c1" id="xr_uid_10"></span> </div>

Comment: Or you could just apply fadeOut() to your element.         $("xr_ap ").fadeOut(5000,"linear")